# Websphere 8.5: Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: deployment, websphere, websphere-8

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy an ear with websphere from an ant ask with jacl:

```
[wsadmin] WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\wsant6857788060872488512jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml]
```

When I try to deploy the ear from the websphere console I get:

```
The following exception occurred. Check log for details. 
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml]
```

Machine details: Win7x64, WebSphere 8.5 x86, using oracle jdk 6u30 x86 (Tested with x64 too).

Others have been able to get the installer to work for them. The WebSphere connection information is correct, as other scripts properly update shared libraries. I'm baffled why it works on other machines and not this one.

Comment: You got a hint there "Check log for details", give us the details

Comment: The exception is referring you to the web.xml of an application in your EAR. Do all the WARs in your EAR have a web.xml file? Can you see if there is an error with any of the web.xml files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much searching (even posted a bounty on a similar problem), I found the issue was comments in the web.xml.

I was lucky enough to have a source branch that didn't have the comments and worked and this other branch that did have the comments and was broke. Different installers from different branches is what allowed the installers to work on some machines, and this other branch installer breaking on my machine.

Removing the comments allowed WebSphere's validator to get past that error... fun stuff... will report it to the WebSphere guys.

Comment: Looks like WebSphere already knows about it, and they have patches available... <sigh> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM49316

Comment: I had similar problem. I didn't have any comments in web.xml. Solution for me was to close project and open it again. I don't understand how it helped...

Answer (score 4):

Please check the application.xml file in ear which has the correct war file name and also check the ejb module jar names. you will get similar error if there is a mismatch in war or ejb jar file names. My case I have issue in the war file name that was wrongly specified in the application.xml

Comment: Up voted. My war file name was misspelled in the application.xml

Comment: My application.xml had an entry for a Bean JAR, which was actually not used

Answer (score 2):

Same error occurred for me, but problem was in the application.xml not the web.xml, spec was inconsistent between application.xml and web.xml.  Web 3.0, J2EE 1.4, should have been Java EE 6.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did these steps:-

1. Go to the EAR
2. Right Click -> Select Properties.
3. Click on Deployment Assembly
4. Add/Remove -WebApps to the EAR.
5. Click on the un-identified project. First remove it and add it again.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time on this issue, I finally found that there was a **duplicate** session config tag in the web.xml. It happened while one of our colleague was merging some code.

It's better you can validate the web.xml, **similar duplicate tags can cause this issue.**

```
 <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            15
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config
```

Comment: in my case it was <welcome-file-list> tag that got duplicated.